# Mathematical function for erfinv function

Tags: statistics

Can u please help me with the formula for erfinv function?

Inverse error function..in terms of log or an exponential formula

error function : φ(z)=12π√e−.5x2
Can I get a similar function for inverse error function?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi, Thank u for your response. I am trying to find a python alternative to SAS probit function. documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/v_006/lefunctionsref/… there any math/python function for it?...I am new to stats...I am not clear on the concept

Comment: The duplicate question is deleted, but there are other questions with the inverse error function series already.